# Why is my last route overriding the css in previous routes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a simple React SPA personal website, and noticed that CSS selectors for routes that are later in the router are overriding previous ones, even when those later routes are not the page in question. For example, here is my app

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} exact></Route>
          <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
          <Route path='/resume' element={<Resume />}></Route>
          <Route path='/projects' element={<Projects />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>
  );
}
```

However, styling for the contact page is being override by the resume page. For example: [font-size being overriden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821nh.png)

I realize I can use class names for higher specificity, but was wondering what is the root cause of this behavior?

Comment: can you share more code.

Comment: IIRC all the routed components have been imported, including any CSS files imported into their files. You'll need to be more specific with your selectors or not use CSS files, i.e. something like CSS-in-JS.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese, that's what I figured. Atal, sure, what do you want to see? The CSS lines in question are just h1 stylers

Comment: If you are not using classes, I assume CSS precedence ordering will take effect. With that being said. Check out the order in which css takes precedence. For example: `<Home/>` will import css that styles an `H1` to red. Then `<Contact/>` imports a style that styles an `H1` to blue. If you go back to `<Home/>`, `<Contact/>` import is still there and supersedes  `<Home/>` because it came after. This may be the issue..

Answer (score 1):

Use different classes for each h1 tag. all CSS files classes and styles work for all components if imported once at any file. so just change CSS and remember to use unique classname for all element you want to style.